# Column names are getting repeated while appending dataframes in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes which i am getting inside a for loop. When I am trying to append the two Dataframes column names are getting populated in between the rows.
I did a bit of research and used lists, but i am unable to make the lists work for me, Here is my code,

```
def generatesalesreport3():
if g_month is not None and g_year is not None:
    if (g_month == '1: January to March'):
        r_month = ['January','February','March']
        r_year = int(g_year)
    elif(g_month == '2: April to June'):
        r_month = ['April', 'May', 'June']
        r_year = int(g_year)
    elif(g_month == '3: July to Septempber'):
        r_month = ['July', 'August', 'September']
        r_year = int(g_year)
    else:
         r_month = ['October', 'November', 'December']
         r_year = int(g_year)

    ra = list()
    rb= list()
    for qmonth in r_month:
        monnum = month_dict[qmonth]
        resultb1 = df_b1.loc[(df_b1['month'] == monnum) & (df_b1['year'] == r_year)]
        resultb2 = df_b2.loc[(df_b2['month'] == monnum) & (df_b2['year'] == r_year)]
        resultb1 = resultb1.append(resultb2)
        print(resultb1)
```

[Image to the result of above code please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHIvD.png)

So, my requirement is i don't want to get those column names in between in the results,after that i get the complete dataframe into one dataframe i have to do some manipulations based on the **Model** column.

Comment: What do you get from `print(type(resultb1))` and `print(resultb1.shape)`? Is it a dataframe with the correct output shape that you expect?

Comment: Hi @Ralf using ` print(type(resultb1))` i get  **<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>** two times which should print only once if it has a single dataframe as we are appending and `print(resultb1.shape)` gives me (3,8) and (1,8). My result should be (4, 8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter out the columns from "resultb2" dataframe and then append. Like:

```
resultb1 = resultb1.append(resultb2[["column1","column2","column3",......]])
print(resultb1)
```